# C# Question With Telerik RadTabStrip

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

So I have a telerik RadTabStrip with RadViews I think it's called. The thing is when I am in the fourth tab and I click any button or link there it posts back and sends me to the first tab but I don't want that, this actually happens when I am clicking a button to delete something, it deletes it but when postback goes back to the first tab so I have to go back to the fourth tab to make sure it deleted. I know it is in my pageload.. How can I improve it?

Thank you

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["BooksID"] != null)
    {
        btnSubmit.Text = "Plus";
        btnOtherSubmit.Text = "Plus";
        theID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["BookID"]);
    }
    else
    {
        btnSubmit.Text = "Minus";
        btnPtherSubmit.Text = "Minus";
        clientID= 0;            
    }

    if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Page1.aspx"))
        {
            MyMultiView.SelectedIndex = 1;
            TabStrip.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        else if(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Page2.aspx"))
        {
            PersonalizationMultiView.SelectedIndex = 2;
            TabStrip.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            MyMultiView.SelectedIndex = 0;
            TabStrip.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       BindField(BookStoreID);

       if (theID > 0)
       {
           BindPr(theID);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide an appropriate question title, if you want to get a answer for it.

Comment: There's an "edit" link below the tags in your question. You can use it to update the title.

Comment: Look for the edit button bellow tags and hit hit to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RadTabStrip doesn't just reset back to the original tab; it's pretty good at keeping its position.  I've never had that issue, only when I wrote code to explcitly change the tab/page view.

The issue is your Request.UriReferrer references is not wrapped with !Page.IsPostBack, so it always sets the first or second tab.

HTH.